# I didn't see any science but

Tags: sentence-meaning

This is from [a YouTube video](https://youtu.be/H0bA72fjHMQ?t=4357).

> **I didn't see any science but** I have to imagine that's the world's
> largest gas pump

My sense is that the part in bold means 'I don't have any evidence but'.

Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what he means is that there was no evidence visible at the museum that the pump was the world's largest, but that he was guessing that it could be.

Comment: Thank you very much.